# How to clear template cache in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, browser-cache

In Angularjs, I have made many html pages for the project.But in one browser the html pages comes from cache so that I can't get new changes in that browser(doing refresh and hard refresh).

Sometime I get new changes in html after hard refresh the page and sometime I didn't get it.

Please give me some solution for it.

My sample for caching:-

```
mainApp.run(['$rootScope','$cacheFactory', function($rootScope,$cacheFactory) {
$cacheFactory.get('$http').removeAll()
.....
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove cached views from the code.

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        if (typeof(current) !== 'undefined'){
            $templateCache.remove(current.templateUrl);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i do it,but i have also one question that if we change some content in html ..it is possible to get that content without page reload or refresh.

Comment: @arshadshaikh for that you need to use build system , or you can go with ides such as atom or webstrom